# Override Slicer Filter Context in Chart (To Show Fuller X-Axis)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Imagine I have a fact table with sales spanning 3 years (2016-2018).  I have a chart showing sales by month (36 points on the X-Axis).  I have a slicer selection to Year = 2018, and Month = June.

Is it possible, with a measure, to show on a chart, the trailing 6 months from the slicer selection?  In other words, with the slicer still set to Year = 2018 and Month = January, can the chart display 6 points (the trailing 6 months)?

How would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would use in this case would be to create a parameter table for the date which doesn't have a relationship with my other tables and use that date for the slicer. Then you'd write the sales measure you use on the chart to read the selected date and return blanks for any dates not within the range you want.

Roughly like this:

```
NewSalesMeasure = 
    VAR SelectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer[Date])
    VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Sales[Date])
    RETURN IF(CurrentDate <= SelectedDate &&
              CurrentDate > DATEADD(SelectedDate, -6, MONTH)
              SUM(Sales[Amount]),
              BLANK()
           )
```

Comment: This approach will work!  However, I have a bunch of other visuals on the page that need to respect the single month that was sliced to.  Any ideas on how to make that happen without re-writing all the measures to be in the "if" context?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't really see a way to have your cake and eat it too. If you want the same slicer to behave in different ways for different visuals, then you'll need to adjust your measures accordingly.

Comment: Hi Alex!  Understood on your point.  I was able to get all visuals to play together by syncing the disconnected slicers with the "connected" slicers on the same page.  Now there is a seamless user experience.  Thanks so much for your assist!

Comment: @JJB Nice. Thanks for that tip. I haven't tried that before.