# How can I display +10 data based on the selected value?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have one table.
It is a table like the following.

```
| ID | value|
------------
| 1  | 123 |
|----|-----|
| 2  | 234 |
|----|-----|
| 3  | 456 |
|----|-----|
| 4  | 123 |
|----|-----|
...
| 98 | 234 |
|----|-----|
| 99 | 456 |
|----|-----|
|100 | 123 |
|----|-----|
```

[image]

I want to display this data on the following screen and acquire +10 data from the selected ID.

left: Slicer
right: filterd_table (dax query)

```
filterd_table = 
var selected = [selected_value]
return filter('Sheet1', 'Sheet1'[ID] >= selected && 'Sheet1'[ID] <= selected + 10)
```

What I want to do is
If 23 is selected, you want to display the tables on the right side from 23 to 32.
Now, regardless of the value chosen, values from 1 to 10 are displayed.

```
Expected value

| ID | value|
------------
| 23  | 123 |
|---- |-----|
| 24  | 234 |
|---- |-----|
| 25  | 456 |
|---- |-----|
| ... | 123 |
|---- |-----|
| 30  | 456 |
|---- |-----|
| 31  | 231 |
|---- |-----|
| 32  | 143 |
|---- |-----|
```

I placed a pbix file on my drive.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-imy23jvPIeRZC73SfDz9Um3EDwzeg7y/view?usp=sharing

I appreciate it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Different problem, but similar logic as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994545/override-slicer-filter-context-in-chart-to-show-fuller-x-axis/) should do the trick.